# mozChannels/mozSampleRate is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, fft

I am using the this within an audio experiment of mine.

```
audiometa: function(){
        channels = audio.mozChannels;
        rate = audio.mozSampleRate;
        frameBufferLength = audio.mozFrameBufferLength;

        fft = new FFT(frameBufferLength / channels, rate);
    },
```

For some reason, mozChannels/mozSampleRate and mozFrameBufferLength is undefined using the latest version of Firefox. Reading the cos, I can't explain myself, why this could happen.

Is there something within the about:config page which I need to turn on? (Have tried it local and on a webserver)

By the way, I am using this example.
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Reading_Audio

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Firefox no longer supports mozChannels, mozSampleRate and mozFrameBufferLength. That would cause an undefined error. The link to the doc you provided has a note that says that API has been deprecated in favor of the W3C Web Audio API. And I searched through the Firefox codebase here:

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/

And those properties do not appear in the Firefox code. I suggest you try using the W3C Web Audio API:

https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API